# Complicated batch rename file problem

Tags: files, regex, batch-rename

I did find the program pyRenamer, but I don't seem to understand it.

I have hundreds of files with name like

`main.php?g2_view=core.DownloadItem&g2_itemId=6027&g2_serialNumber=3`

here actually only the itemId and the serialNumber does change.
serialNumber is 1 or 2 or 3.

I just need to rename them with file suffix `jpg`, and something like "downloaditem".

Comment: Please clarify your post by editing it to be more clear and coherent. Thanks!@

Comment: It is true that studying some parts of computer science can help you to understand regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all of these items in the same program, use this script to rename each of them to 'download%.jpg' replacing % with a number.
Replace the 'main.php*' with '*' if not all of the file names start with 'main.php'.

This script assumes that your files are in your Download directory (folder), Change '$HOME/Downloads' to whatever folder they are in.

```
cd "$HOME/Downloads"
num=0
for item in main.php*; do
    mv "$item" "download${num}.jpg"
    num="`expr "$num" + 1`"
done
```

Or this one-line version if you want:

```
cd "$HOME/Downloads"; num=0; for item in main.php*; do mv "$item" "download${num}.jpg"; num="`expr "$num" + 1`"; done
```

You can run that command in a terminal. Open a terminal with CTRL+ALT+T then copy the one-line version and paste it into the terminal with CTRL+SHIFT+V.